# How to query a field by name on mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

How can I get the same query's result :

```
Test.where(name: "Depeche Mode").first.last_connection_date
```

Changing `last_connection_date` by a String

```
@desired_field = "last_connection_date"
Test.where(name: "Depeche Mode").first.(@desired_field)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `send`

```
Test.where(name: "Depeche Mode").send(@desired_field.to_sym)
```